# Как отменить влияние функций mysql на ключ ассоциативного массива?

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

В таблице хранится дата (в стандартном виде для mysql), если в SELECT добавить функции форматирования типа DATE_FORMAT(col_name, 'определённый формат') то при получение результата как ассоциативный массив получим вместо col_name ключа, ключ - DATE_FORMAT(col_name, 'определённый формат'). Как убрать влияние функции на ключ массива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, решение нашел. Нужно использовать конструкцию типа DATE_FORMAT(col_name, 'определённый формат') as col_name.